# Python Dictionary automatically check if value does not exist and return a default value

Tags: python

I am new to python I am writing code to count the frequency of numbers in a list
However I get KeyError. How to automatically check if value does not exist and return a default value. My code is below

```
arr = [1,1,2,3,2,1]
freq={}
for i in arr:
   freq[i] += freq[i] + 1
```

Comment: `freq.get("key", "default")`

Comment: I don't think you should use `+=` when updating your frequency; your values will progress 0,1,3,7,15,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can leverage the get method of a dictionary. You can simply do

```
arr=[1,1,2,3,2,1]
freq={}
for i in arr:
    freq[i] = freq.get(i,0)+1
```

Please Google for basic question like this before asking on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You want the dictionary's `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the python library, there is a `defaultdict` which can help you here

[Documentation for the defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import collections

arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
freq = collections.defaultdict(int)  # The `int` makes the default value 0
for i in arr:
    freq[i] += freq[i] + 1
```

When you try to access a `defaultdict` with a key that is not yet present, it executes the function that you supply when creating it - Calling `int()` without any arguments gives you a zero.

Sidenote: It seems that you want to count the occurances of numbers in your array, then you'd want to change your updating to

```
for i in arr:
    freq[i] += 1
```

Also, the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object might be of interest for you.